# passing c/c++ dylib function taking pointer to VBA on mac

Tags: c++, macos, vba, gcc, dylib

I am actually playing with interfacing c/c++ and the VBA of Excel-2011 for mac. How could I design, in the dylib, functions taking pointers as parameters, or references ? Or arrays ? Or even simple structs ? Under windows, `VARIANT` let's me do everything, but I cannot resort to it under OS X (or even under linux).

Just as comment, up to now, I can do things like these for (involving "simple" types) :

I have the following code configuration : in tmp3class.h :

```
class TheClass
{
      public:
            double mysum(double x ,double y);
};
```

in tmp3class.cpp :

```
#include "./tmp3class.h"

double TheClass::mysum(double x ,double y)
{
      return x+y ;
}
```

and in tmp3.cpp :

```
#include "./tmp3class.h"

extern "C"
{
      double THESUM(double x, double y)
      {
            TheClass TheObj ;
            double res = TheObj.mysum(x,y);
            return res ;
      }
}
```

I compile this with :

```
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -Wall -g -c ./tmp3class.cpp -o ./tmp3obj.o
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -dynamiclib .tmp3.cpp ./tmp3obj.o -o ./tmp3.dylib
```

and then in the vba I do this :

```
Declare Function THESUM Lib "/Users/XXXXXX/Documents/GITHUBRepos/DYLIBS/MyFirstDylib/tmp3.dylib" (ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double) As Double

Function THESUM_VBA(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
    THESUM_VBA = THESUM(x, y)
End Function
```

and the function `THESUM_VBA` works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer (designed thank to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/205277)) in the case of arrays : to pass an array (of double) from c++ to excel-2011's (mac) VBA, the c++ function should have in its signature a `double *` representing the pointer to the first coefficient of the array, an `int` (or a `long` or etc) reprensenting the size of the array. For instance, a function taking an array and multiplying all its coefficients by a parameter value would be coded like this : the c++ code is :

```
extern "C"
{
      void multarray(double * array, int size, double coeff)
      {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
            {
                  array[i]*=coeff;
            }
      }
}
```

compiled with :

```
g++ -m32 -Wall -g -c ./tmp4.cpp
g++ -m32 -dynamiclib ./tmp4.o -o ./tmp4.dylib
```

Now the VBA should reference the dylib as follows :

```
Declare Sub multarray Lib "/Users/XXXXXX/Documents/GITHUBRepos/DYLIBS/MyFirstDylib/tmp4.dylib" (ByRef firstcoeff As Double, ByVal size As Long, ByVal coeff As Double)
```

The first parameter of `multarray` represent the first coefficient of the array, *and must be passed by reference*. Here is an exemple of utilisation :

```
Public Sub DoIt()
    Dim multarraofdoubles(3) As Double
    multarraofdoubles(0) = -1.3
    multarraofdoubles(1) = 4.6
    multarraofdoubles(2) = -0.67
    multarraofdoubles(3) = 3.13
    Dim coeff As Double
    coeff = 2#
    Call multarray(multarraofdoubles(0), 4, coeff)
End Sub
```

The aforementioned [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/205277) contains many other interesting examples, for strings (with `BSTR`'s), array of strings, simple structs etc, that could be easily adapted to `gcc` and this mac OS (/linux) context. I am thinking of designing a simple `VARIANT`class handling all of this.